# How To Use Events In Controls For Mutual Communications?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, notifications, controls

This is a question about programming techniques. The idea is this:

1. `control A` fires events (normal)
2. `control A` listens to events (of other threads / controls)

I want to implement the 2nd one. But in a safe and most modular way. So the control mustn't know who is firing the event only that it is fired. I think there are lots of ways to do that. Which one is the best ? Let's say a form is firing the event `LoadImages` and wants to listen to event `ImagesLoaded`.

- threads / controls call a function of `control A` and notify it in this way that they'are done *(but they know about `control A` and it's methods)*
- `control A` subscribes to events of threads / controls and knows when they are fired *(master thread that knows about everything must connect them via event subscribing)*
- `control A` starts a waiting thread that calls a blocking function and fires the `ImagesLoaded` event at the end when the function is done *(`control A` knows about threads / controls that do some jobs)*
- `control A` calls either a function or fires an event while passing a `callback` function as parameter *(no one knows anything except what they have to do)*
- ... ?

Which one gives me most modularity ? Are there even more ways to implement 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

The technique you mentioned is usually achieved by asynchronous calls and *callback*s that are executed when the asynchronous call is completed. Having said that, it seems like [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) fits your situation. You can execute blocking/long-running jobs with its `DoWork` handler and bind what's to be done when it's finished to `RunWorkerCompleted` event (updating the UI especially).